# Mongoose geolocation dynamic max distance

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currenty I'm working with MongoDB and I have a users collection with the following schema:

```
const DEFAULT_JOB_RADIUS = 5000 // In meters

const settingsSchema = new Schema({
  jobRadius: {
    type: Number,
    default: DEFAULT_JOB_RADIUS
  }
})

const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    trim: true,
    type: String
  },
  lastName: {
    trim: true,
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    trim: true,
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  token: {
    type: String
  },
  fcmToken: {
    type: String
  },
  lastLocation: {
    type: pointSchema
  },
  settings: {
    type: settingsSchema,
    default: settingsSchema
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

Point schema looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const pointSchema = new Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Point'],
    default: 'Point'
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    default: [0, 0],
    index: '2dsphere'
  }
});

module.exports = pointSchema
```

Every user has a `jobRadius` property. This property represents the max distance of the user to any point.

In my code, I need to fetch all the users that are near a specific point.
Here is what I'm currently trying to do:

```
async getNearbyUsers(point) {
    const users = await this.model.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: point,
          distanceField: "dist.calculated",
          maxDistance: '$settings.jobRadius',
          spherical: true
        }
      }
    ])

    return users
  }
```

This code doesn't work. It always bring me all the users inside the collection.
If I change the `maxDistance` field to something like that, it works:

```
maxDistance: 1
```

My questions is - How can I perform such aggregation, where the max distance is dynamic and specific to each user?

Comment: Not possible to use document field in the `$geoNear`. Here is the [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34766).

Comment: @Ashh is there any other way that I could exectue this query?

Comment: You can calucluate the distance `dist.calculated` field first using above `$geoNear` and then can use `$match` stage using `$expr` with `$lte` `$gte` operators.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I managed to solve this, with the help of @Ashh
I first calculate the distance between the users and the point and then I filter all the users that their radius property exceeds the distance.

```
async getNearbyUsers(point) {
    const users = await this.model.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: point,
          distanceField: "dist.calculated",
          spherical: true
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $gt: ['$settings.jobRadius', '$dist.calculated']
          }
        }
      }
    ])

    return users
  }
```